# Meaning of 则 in 欲速则不达？

Tags: word-requests, word, idioms

What is the meaning of 则 in 欲速则不达? Does it mean fortune, wealth, success? I couldn't figure out out.

Comment: No, see e.g. jukuu: "The more haste, she less speed", 则：conjunction，used before the 2nd clause (不达) to indicate the conditional relation

Comment: So it means "then"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

欲 －－ willing, want

速 －－ speedy, quick

则 －－ then, but

不 －－ not, negative

达 －－ arrive, done

*If you want to finish it quicker, then you probably can't get it done (correctly).*

Answer (score 2):

This `则` means "then" in English, like the Chinese word `就`.